# Macro to repeat itself on the next rown down

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have this macro which works ok on the first row, but once it has completed I want it to run again on the next row down and paste the result on the next row down on the "results" sheet and continue the process through the whole document until it reaches the last record - (there are approx. 5300 records in my spreadsheet)

```
Sub Macro2()
    ' Macro2 Macro

    Range("A2:BW2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Lookup").Select
    Range("F3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("F3:V3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Result").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

So basically I am copying the first row of data on sheet named "amps_job_history", it them pastes this data into a sheet called "lookup", once the data is pasted there a formula does a calculation that marries the data up with data from another worksheet.  I then want to copy the original data plus the extra 3 columns that have been connected to the data with the formulas and the paste it into the sheet called "result".  I then want it to go back to the first sheet "amps_job_hisotry" move down to the next row of data and repeat the process and when it pastes the data into the "result" page it need to past on the next row down and so on and so on until it reaches the last record.

Answer (score 1):

I think this loop is what you are looking for.

```
Sub Macro2()
    ' Macro2 Macro
    Dim rw As Long

    With Worksheets("amps_job_history")
        For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            With Intersect(.Range("A:BW"), .Rows(rw))
                Worksheets("Lookup").Range("F3").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
            End With

            With Worksheets("Lookup")
                With .Range("F3:V3")
                    Worksheets("Result").Range("A1").Offset(rw - 1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
                End With
            End With
        Next rw
    End With

End Sub
```

The rows from the source data in the amps_job_history and the destination Result worksheet are shifted down one more row on each loop. The transitional F3:V3 range in the Lookup worksheet remains the same through out.

I've use direct value transfer rather than copy, paste special, values and the [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) provide explicit parent worksheet referencing without the use of the [Range .Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197597.aspx) or [Range .Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221681.aspx) methods.